# .Net 5 Web API CORS LocalHost

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a .Net 5 Web API and I am having issues with CORS only when I am running locally (aka localhost). When I have deployed my app to Azure I can access my API just fine from my Blazor app.

Class Startup.cs

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
```

Class: Startup.cs
Method: ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    //didn't work
    //options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    //{
    //    builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost");
    //});

    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44373/", "https://myawesomesite")
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowCredentials();
                      });
});
```

Class: Startup.cs
Method: Configure

```
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Comment: Can you try without `WithOrigins`?

Comment: We had exactly the same problem with Angular App + WebAPI server. Don't remember the exact reason (I think something with ports in headers), therefore cannot post an answer. As a workaround we started Chrome with the Angular app from cmd with  --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/tmp/chrome" parameters. Than it won't care about CORS.

Comment: How do you test your API locally?

Comment: This solution was working, then I worked the project from a different computer, once I merged back I have been getting CORS problems.

Comment: The one I have mentioned in the answer is working fine on my side and we are testing our API via POSTMAN and the from frontend as well using axios.

Comment: Just to be sure, Postman also throws CORS problem?

Comment: Postman is working, but the Blazor app is not

Comment: Blazor runs in Browser, right? Postman does not care about CORS. Browser (AFAIK Chrome at least) does not support localhost as a valid origin, so it fails. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove trailing "/" from your local host url and for the test you can try to remove .AllowCredentials().

And use this syntax:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44373", 
                              "https://myawesomesite")
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                      }));
```

and your UseCors method should be between UseRouting and UseAuthourization

```
app.UseRouting()
....
.....
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

....
....
app.UseAuthorization(); // if you need the one
```

Comment: This works for Brave and not FireFox. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What I have on my side working properly as below.

Class: Startup.cs

Method: ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(c =>  
  { 
    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());  
  });
```

Class: Startup.cs

Method: Configure

```
app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

Try this, let me know if it helps.

Comment: No dice, same issue

Comment: How about know, I have updated the answer. try again.

Comment: No dice, same issue

Comment: have you tried a clean build? a different browser? postman? or tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: I've tried all of that with no success, but, postman seems to be working

Comment: Well quite strange, please wait for a senior community member to answer.

Comment: Postman is always working since only the browser checks Cors but postman doesn't.